# exportdata from cassandra into csv files

Tags: c#, cassandra, export-to-csv

Hi guys i would like to get data in a specified table in cassandra and save it into csv file .Here what i did

```
//using c# api
            //  Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("192.168.0.214").Build();
              Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1").Build();
             List<string> lstOfKeyspaces =cluster.Metadata.GetKeyspaces().ToList<string>();
             ISession session = cluster.Connect("integrationobjects");
             //get tables in the keysapce
             List<string> lstString = cluster.Metadata.GetTables("integrationobjects").ToList<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection succeeded");
         //   Console.ReadLine();
            RowSet resultRequest = session.Execute("select json * from emp");
```

Any help would be appreciated in order to save results into csv file.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Use Cqlsh [COPY](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) TO Command**

Login To Cqlsh then use the below command :

```
COPY emp TO 'exp.csv';
```

Comment: This is a cqlsh command, you can't use it in Cassandra Driver

Comment: Is there a way , to get the same result using cassandra Driver? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as traversing the RowSet your query is returning. Something like that should be enough:

```
// Open the file for output...
...

// Loop over all the rows
IEnumerable<Row> rowEnumerator = resultRequest.GetEnumerator();
while (rowEnumerator.MoveNext()) {
    // Get the row
    Row r = rowEnumerator.Current;

    // Prepare a new line
    List<string> values = new List<string>;

    // Loop over all the columns of the row
    IEnumerator<Object> colEnumerator = r.GetEnumerator();
    while (colEnumerator.MoveNext()) {
        values.Add(...); // Stack the strings here 
    }
    // Create the row
    string line = String.Join(",", values.ToArray());

    // Output line to file
    // ...
}
// Close the file
...
```

Comment: please what should i put here  values.Add(...); in the add , thanks and sorry

Comment: would you please help me finish the code you gave , am stack thank you a lot